# iOS share to facebook/twitter button images

Tags: ios, facebook, image, twitter, share

I want to enable users in my app to share to facebook and twitter. However, I don't want to simply use text buttons such as "Share to facebook" but rather use images with each companies respective logos/icons. My problem is I can't find any "official" share images for iOS on either companies website. The only link I found for twitter was inactive. Where can I find these official share to facebook/twitter images which are approved for use in third party applications?

Comment: do google  got your solution....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be it helps, see the following links.

- https://about.twitter.com/resources/buttons#tweet
- https://www.facebookbrand.com/

Comment: sorry this is the proper twitter url for this question: https://about.twitter.com/company/brand-assets